# Select time field dynamically in django forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am working on a project of a website to reserve football fields by using Django.

In the project, I have 3 models: **football field** (name, address), **team** (information about the captain of the team) and **reservation** (football field, team, date and time of reservation):

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField('Team Name', max_length=60)
    captain_first_name = models.CharField('Captain Name',max_length=30)
    captain_second_name = models.CharField('Captain Second Name', max_length=30) 
    captain_email = models.EmailField('User Email', blank = True)
    captain_phone = models.CharField('Captain Phone', max_length=9)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.team_name

class Football_Field(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Field name', max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField('Field address', max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Reservation(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank = True, on_delete = PROTECT)
    football_field = models.ForeignKey(Football_Field, blank = True, on_delete = PROTECT)
    reservation_date = models.DateField('Reservation Date')
    reservation_time = models.TimeField('Reservation Time', default=dt.time(00, 00))
```

I create a reservation form as well, like this:

```
class ReservationForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = "__all__"
    labels = {
        'team': 'Select your team',
        'football_field': 'Select football field',
        'reservation_date': 'Select reservation date', 
        'reservation_time': 'Select time of reservation'
    }        

    widgets = {
        'team' : forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:500px', 'class': 'form-select'}),
        'football_field' : forms.Select(attrs={'style': 'width:500px', 'class': 'form-select'}),
        'reservation_date' : forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width:200px', 'type': 'date'}), 
        'reservation_time': forms.Select(choices=HOUR_CHOICES, attrs={'format':'%H', 'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width:200px', 'type': 'time', 'required step':"3600"})
    }
```

The problem is how to connect time field selection in form with selected `football_field` and `reservation date` (to not display time which has been already booked). My idea was to filter dynamically `choices` in `reservation_time` based on selected fields and reservations in my database but not sure if it is possible.

I will be really grateful for any suggestion or tips.

Comment: Try to add a boolean field which will update when user will do reservation for perticular object than you can filter all object in selct tag by referencing boolean value

Comment: Adding a `clean_reservation_time` method on your form class is a simple way of doing this. See this example in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute.